# Can anyone tell me why i keep encountering this error - [TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'strict']

Tags: python, pandas, keyword, pandas-datareader

This is my simple and small code. I have uninstalled and installed requests, pandas and pandas_datareader. Please tell me what to do now.

```
import pandas as pd
import pandas_datareader as dr


dr.data.get_data_yahoo('ibm')
```

Here is the full error:

```
runfile('C:/Users/Vidur/Desktop/analysis.py', wdir='C:/Users/Vidur/Desktop')
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-1-eac6a3eb07f4>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('C:/Users/Vidur/Desktop/analysis.py', wdir='C:/Users/Vidur/Desktop')

  File "C:\Users\Vidur\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 786, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\Users\Vidur\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 110, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "C:/Users/Vidur/Desktop/analysis.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pandas as pd

  File "C:\Users\Vidur\Anaconda3\pandas\__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
    __import__(dependency)

  File "C:\Users\Vidur\Anaconda3\numpy\__init__.py", line 140, in <module>
    from . import _distributor_init

  File "C:\Users\Vidur\Anaconda3\numpy\_distributor_init.py", line 26, in <module>
    WinDLL(os.path.abspath(filename))

  File "C:\Users\Vidur\Anaconda3\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 356, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)

OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application
```

Comment: Do you have the requests package installed?

Comment: Can you post the full stacktrace?

Comment: @jordanm Im not sure what exactly stacktrace is, but i have edited and updated the question and fully copied and pasted the error.

Comment: @EdekiOkoh Yes i have the requests package installed

Comment: How did you install Anaconda? That error indicates that the compiled resources are for a different operating system or architecture.